# How to calculate the matrix for an object mirroring over a point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have found the following task:
Give the homogeneous 4x4 matrix describing a object mirroring over the point  $P( 1 , 3 , 0 )$ and there solution $\left[\begin{array}{cccc} -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$
But how to they come to that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection of $(x,y,z)$ about $P(1,3,0)$ is $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ iff the mid-point of $(x,y,z)$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is $P$.
Thus$$\frac{x+x_1}2=1\\\frac{y+y_1}2=3\\\frac{z+z_1}2=0$$from where we get the reflection map $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(2-x,6-y,-z)=(2,6,0)+(-x,-y,-z)$.